# Negative row and column in terrain following algorithm

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx-11, terrain

I'm trying to do terrain following, and I get a negative camera position in the xz plane. Now I get an out of boundary exception, because the row or the col is negative. How would I transform the cell of the grid to the origin correctly, giving negative camera coordinates.

Here is the two functions

```
int cGrid::getHeightmapEntry(int row, int col)
{
    return m_heightmap[row * 300 + col];
}

float cGrid::getHeight(float x, float z, float _width, float _depth, int _cellSpacing)
{
    // Translate on xz-plane by the transformation that takes
    // the terrain START point to the origin.
    x = ((float)_width / 2.0f) + x;
    z = ((float)_depth / 2.0f) - z;

    // Scale down by the transformation that makes the 
    // cellspacing equal to one.  This is given by 
    // 1 / cellspacing since; cellspacing * 1 / cellspacing = 1.
    x /= (float)_cellSpacing;
    z /= (float)_cellSpacing;

    // From now on, we will interpret our positive z-axis as
    // going in the 'down' direction, rather than the 'up' direction.
    // This allows to extract the row and column simply by 'flooring'
    // x and z:

    float col = ::floorf(x);
    float row = ::floorf(z);

    if (row < 0 || col<0)
    {
        row = 0;
    }
    // get the heights of the quad we're in:
    // 
    //  A   B
    //  *---*
    //  | / |
    //  *---*  
    //  C   D

    float A = getHeightmapEntry(row, col);
    float B = getHeightmapEntry(row, col + 1);
    float C = getHeightmapEntry(row + 1, col);
    float D = getHeightmapEntry(row + 1, col + 1);

    //
    // Find the triangle we are in:
    //

    // Translate by the transformation that takes the upper-left
    // corner of the cell we are in to the origin.  Recall that our 
    // cellspacing was nomalized to 1.  Thus we have a unit square
    // at the origin of our +x -> 'right' and +z -> 'down' system.
    float dx = x - col;
    float dz = z - row;

    // Note the below compuations of u and v are unneccessary, we really
    // only need the height, but we compute the entire vector to emphasis
    // the books discussion.
    float height = 0.0f;
    if (dz < 1.0f - dx)  // upper triangle ABC
    {
        float uy = B - A; // A->B
        float vy = C - A; // A->C

        // Linearly interpolate on each vector.  The height is the vertex
        // height the vectors u and v originate from {A}, plus the heights
        // found by interpolating on each vector u and v.
        height = A + Lerp(0.0f, uy, dx) +  Lerp(0.0f, vy, dz);
    }
    else // lower triangle DCB
    {
        float uy = C - D; // D->C
        float vy = B - D; // D->B

        // Linearly interpolate on each vector.  The height is the vertex
        // height the vectors u and v originate from {D}, plus the heights
        // found by interpolating on each vector u and v.
        height = D + Lerp(0.0f, uy, 1.0f - dx) +  Lerp(0.0f, vy, 1.0f - dz);
    }

    return height;
}
```

[image]

```
float height = m_Grid.getHeight(position.x, position.y, 49 * 300, 49 * 300, 6.1224489795918367f);
    if (height != 0)
    {
        position.y = height + 10.0f;
    }

    m_Camera.SetPosition(position.x, position.y, position.z);


bool cGrid::readRawFile(std::string fileName, int m, int n)
{

    // A height for each vertex
    std::vector<BYTE> in(m*n);
    std::ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    if (!inFile)
        return false;
    inFile.read(
        (char*)&in[0], // buffer
        in.size());// number of bytes to read into buffer
    inFile.close();
    // copy BYTE vector to int vector
    m_heightmap.resize(n*m);
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++)
        m_heightmap[i] = (float)((in[i])/255)*50.0f;
    return true;
}

m_Grid.readRawFile("castlehm257.raw", 50, 50);
```

Comment: I'd recommend removing the dx11 tag and adding the graphics tag.. or something else more germane -- you'll need to hit a broader audience for this question.  Also try posting to gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks did your suggestions

Comment: oh, for whatever reason I thought you could only have 4 tags.

Comment: I have checked your maths and found no problem. Perhaps it would help if you could provide more information, such as the definition of `m_heightmap`, and the actual values you’re passing to `cGrid::getHeight` when it fails.

Comment: @Entropy I have edited the post. please let me know if you need more information. I'm still getting out of bound exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I infer that you’re storing a 50 by 50 matrix inside a 300 by 300 matrix, to represent a grid of 49 by 49 cells. I also infer that `m_Grid` is an object of type `cGrid`. Your code appears to contain the following errors:

Argument(2) of call `m_Grid.getHeight` is not a `z` value.

Argument(3) of call `m_Grid.getHeight` is inconsistent with argument(5).

Argument(4) of call `m_Grid.getHeight` is inconsistent with argument(5).

Implicit cast of literal `float` to `int` in argument(5) of call `m_Grid.getHeight` - the value will be truncated.

Try changing your function call to this:

```
float height = m_Grid.getHeight(position.x, position.z, 49 * cellspacing, 49 * cellspacing, cellspacing);
```

-- where `cellspacing` is as defined in your diagram.

Also, try changing parameter(5) of `cGrid::getHeight` from `int _cellSpacing` to `float _cellSpacing`.

(I have edited this answer a couple of times as my understanding of your code has evolved.)

Comment: thanks alot, but the terrain is following right now but its not accurate, at some hills its not following at all, and the following is not accurate, what should I do to improve it

Comment: I suggest you make sure you’ve followed ALL of my suggestions, including the one about changing the `int` to `float`. I suggest you also check your code for other incorrect uses of `int` instead of `float`. I suggest you consider changing `m_heightmap[i] = (float)((in[i])/255)*50.0f;` to `m_heightmap[i] = ((float)in[i])*50.0f/255.0f;`.

Comment: And if those suggestions don’t solve your problem, I suggest you post more of your code (possibly starting with that which renders the image of the terrain) and more information about the nature of your problem. Consider posting this as a separate question, and then posting the link to it in a comment here. I also recommend that you show the declarations of variables and object instances when seeking help, to make it clear what type each object is.